Lock data bag user on chef
I want to disable data bag user using option "lock". It gives me error, saying lock option does not exist, when i run chef-client.
Looks like "lock" action does exists when I look on chef documentation.
https://docs.chef.io/resources/user/#actions
This is what I did.

knife data bag edit users user1

And then, I change action to lock.
{
  "name": "data_bag_item_users_user1",
  "json_class": "Chef::DataBagItem",
  "chef_type": "data_bag_item",
  "data_bag": "users",
  "raw_data": {
    "id": "user1",
    "username": "user1",
    "password": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "uid": "833",
    "gid": "user1",
    "home": "/home/user1",
    "shell": "/bin/bash",
    "comment": "user1",
    "action": "create",
    "ssh_auth_key": "false"
  }
}

When i run chef-client it gives me error:

Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Option action must be equal to one
of: nothing, create, remove, modify, manage!


Please include your recipe code, and versions you are using.

Also looking at your databag structure, "action" is a string "create" ("action": "create",) or "lock". Whereas the Chef resource action requires a Ruby symbol :create or :lock. Passing a string like action "lock" in recipe won't work.

Hmm. actually, Chef (16.4.41) seems to convert the (action) string to symbol if required.
